# Better ways to write SQL statement in DB2 which makes use of "EXISTS" keyword

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have written below SQL in an RPGLE program. Intent is to update the header file (TC400F) if no corresponding records exist in detail file (TC401F). Are there better ways of doing this? By better, I mean that would make the query run faster or would make it look more cleaner.

```
Exec SQL UPDATE  TC400F                     
            SET  T40STS = '05',             
                 T40OFL = '1'               
          WHERE  T40SID = :K#T41SID AND     
                 T40PID = :K#T41PID AND     
     NOT EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM TC401F WHERE
                 T41SID = :K#T41SID AND     
                 T41PID = :K#T41PID );
```

Comment: "Better" in what way? What's your criteria of "better"?

Comment: Better Performance wise, readability wise, maintainability wise.Consider this question as one from one from an SQL noob trying to improve skills

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Exec SQL UPDATE  TC400F f1                     
         SET    (f1.T40STS, f1.T40OFL) = ('05', '1')             
         WHERE  f1.T40SID = :K#T41SID AND     
                f1.T40PID = :K#T41PID AND     
         NOT EXISTS  
         ( 
           SELECT * FROM TC401F f2 
           WHERE (f1.T41SID, f1.T41PID) = (f2.T41SID, f2.T41PID)
         );
```

Comment: That is exactly the same with the terms rearranged. How is it better?

Comment: I was not aware that the values and fields to be updated could be mentioned inside brackets. Same with the where clause. So though not very different to what i wrote, its informative.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing. Already not using twice the values but rather using a key with the key inside the "Exist" can be interpreted differently by the SQL optimizer (maybe it is more powerful on large tables). What is more, one gains in readability. And then it learns at the same time some techniques to what I see. :)

Comment: ....constant folding during the optimizer stage is likely to simply place back the parameter reference, rather than checking against the table, since that would normally be faster.  It is more readable/maintainable, in that if there are multiple items updated in bulk you only need to mention the set of key fields once.

Answer (score 0):

You have not done anything here that explicitly restricts performance. The optimizer is pretty smart these days. Most of the things that affect SQL performance are external to the statement. Best to write the statement to be  semantically correct (as you have above), and let the optimizer do it's thing. Then if you see performance issues, then investigate them with then `Explain` tools in `Run SQL Scripts`. Most likely your performance issues will derive from incorrect indexes.

Comment: Thanks Murph. Its the semantic correctness that I wanted to confirm. There are so many better ways to write SQL statements that I have decided to take expert help every time I write a slightly complicated SQL. And it has helped to improve. A few months before, I would have written this sql as 2 different parts. First set a variable if records are present in TC400F. Then if that flag is true, perform the update. The same question was posted on the code review SE website but got no response. So will be posting on SO going forward. If this is not right, please let me know

Comment: You might get some close or down votes by posting code review type questions here, but I don't think there are many IBM i folks over on Code Review though

Answer (score 0):

```
Exec SQL UPDATE  TC400F                     
            SET  T40STS = '05',             
                 T40OFL = '1'               
          WHERE  (t40sts <> '05' or t40ofl <> '1')
                 and T40SID = :K#T41SID 
                 AND T40PID = :K#T41PID
                 and      
     NOT EXISTS  (SELECT onefieldhere FROM TC401F WHERE
                 T41SID = :K#T41SID AND     
                 T41PID = :K#T41PID );
```

Add a little optimistic code don't update what is already set.
Please don't make the as400 an orphan by ending a line with an operator that is the start of the next line.  Optimistic updates are probably fastest when values are already set because it knows its already done.  You could make it better by using the alias field names so someone in the future will know what a t40ofl is.  Select only one field from the exists clause so sql won't have to pull in a whole row.

Comment: True, not updating a row is faster than updating it - mostly in that you don't have to take the lock.  You still have to search for the row(s), which hopefully there's an index for the two parameterized fields (or the lock might consume less than the search).  Note that `<>` conditions are inherently "expensive" given the percentage of rows that match, so in most cases are likely to be checked last.  Also, I would be very surprised if `EXISTS` isn't optimized to use a constant instead of any field reference.